# Java Array - sort numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment to do where I need to take numbers from an array I was given, int[] array1 = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87}, and list them in the arrays: positive, negative and duplicate.

Here is the code I have so far, but I'm stuck with these duplicate numbers. I don't think I know how to get them from this array. I think I would need to check after I get the positive and negative arrays, but I'm not sure how. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
{

```
int[] array1 = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87}, pos, neg, dup;
int positive = 0;
int negative = 0;
int duplicate = 0;


for (int i : array1)

{
    if (i >= 0)
    {
        positive++;
    } 
    else if (i < 0){

        negative++;
    }

    else 
    {
        duplicate++;
    }
}


pos = new int[positive];
neg = new int[negative];
dup = new int[duplicate];


positive = 0;
negative = 0;
duplicate = 0;


for (int i : array1)
{
    if (i >= 0)
    {
        pos[positive] = i;
        positive++;
    } 
    else if (i < 0)
    {
        neg[negative] = i;
        negative++;
    }
    else dup[duplicate] = i;
        negative++;
}

   System.out.print("\nPositive array: ");
for (int i: pos)
{
    System.out.print(" " + i);
}

System.out.print("\nNegative array: ");
for (int i: neg)
{
    System.out.print(" " + i);
}
System.out.print("\nDuplicate array: ");
for (int i: dup)
{
    System.out.print(" " + i);
}
```

}
 }

Comment: Yes counting duplicates will be easiest to do on its own. If you go through the list of numbers by hand, how would you determine how many duplicates there are? Can you describe in words step by step what you would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using only basic arrays. I have introduced a result array where I keep track if the number in the original array is positive, negative or a duplicate.

```
int[] array1 = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
int[] result = new int[array1.length];

int value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    value = array1[i];
    if (value >= 0) {
        result[i] = 1;
    } else {
        result[i] = -1;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array1.length; j++) {
        if (array1[i] == array1[j]) {
            result[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

System.out.print("\nPositive array: ");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i] == 1) {
        System.out.print(" " + array1[i]);
    }
}
System.out.print("\nNegative array: ");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i] == -1) {
        System.out.print(" " + array1[i]);
    }
}
System.out.print("\nDuplicate array: ");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i] == 0) {
        System.out.print(" " + array1[i]);
    }
}
```

Output is

> Positive array:  12 23 0 43 545
>   Negative array:  -22 -4 -55 -999 -87
>   Duplicate array:  43 12 0

Comment: Try having more than 2 duplicate elements in the input array. Your duplicate array will print duplicate numbers multiple times which is not correct.

Comment: That is intentional and how I wanted to present the result, all numbers in the input array is printed in one, and only one, of the 3 categories.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sortArrays(){

ArrayList<Integer> positiveList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> negativeList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i : array1){//getting all positive nums & negative nums
if(i >= 0)
positiveList.add(i);
else{
negativeList.add(i);
   }
}

int counter = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();//Will hold duplicates

for(int i : array1){//The actual check for duplicates
for(int k : array1){
if(i == k)
   counter++;
  }

if(counter > 1)
duplicates.add(i);
counter = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume this question should be solved using only arrays (int[]), maybe you should ask the OP first if other collection types are allowed?

Comment: You're probably right. That would make this quite a bit more code & far more cumbersome, however.

Comment: He never indicated his positive/negative lists should not contain duplicates

Answer (score 0):

This type of logic in your code will never update the duplicate count because if **i is not greater than or equal to** 0 AND **i is not strictly less than 0**, then what will i be?

```
//incorrect -> will never go into the last else
if (i >= 0)
{
    positive++;
} 
else if (i < 0){

    negative++;
}
else 
{
    duplicate++;
}
```

My suggestion is, initially, just put every number in a HashMap (convert the int to an Integer object first) where it is the key and the value should be its count. Then iterate the HashMap and find the positives, negatives and duplicates

Comment: Yo this guy definitely does not know about hashmaps.

Comment: @Matthew, convert the ints to Integer objects before putting into the hashmap

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use for loop more than once. You may try with this code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] array1 = { 12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87 };
    printSummary(array1);
}

public static void printSummary(int[] nums) {
    Set<Integer> foundNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    List<Integer> positiveNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> negativeNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> duplicateNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] >= 0) {
            positiveNums.add(nums[i]);
        } else {
            negativeNums.add(nums[i]);
        }

        if (foundNumbers.contains(nums[i])) {
            duplicateNums.add(nums[i]);
        }
        foundNumbers.add(nums[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Positive numbers: " + positiveNums + " (Total: " + positiveNums.size() + ")");
    System.out.println("Negative numbers: " + negativeNums + " (Total: " + negativeNums.size() + ")");
    System.out.println("Duplicate numbers: " + duplicateNums + " (Total: " + duplicateNums.size() + ")");
}
```

This gives following output,

```
Positive numbers: [12, 23, 0, 43, 545, 43, 12, 0] (Total: 8)
Negative numbers: [-22, -4, -55, -999, -87] (Total: 5)
Duplicate numbers: [43, 12, 0] (Total: 3)
```

Comment: Well, I don't think OP has mentioned anywhere that it should not print duplicate numbers so the numbers are printed as they were in the input array. If one needs to print unique numbers only, just replace positiveNums  in sop with new HashSet<>(positiveNums)

Answer (score -2):

you can use this

```
int[] pos=new int[array1.length];
int[] neg=new int[array1.length];
int[] zeros=new int[array1.length];
int[] l1=new int[array1.length];
int[] duplicate=new int[array1.length];

int number=0;
for(int i=0;i<=array1.length;i++){
    number=array1[i];
    if(l1.contains(number) && duplicate.contains(number))
        duplicate[duplicate.length+1]=number;
    else
        l1[l1.length+1]=number;
    if(number<0)
        neg[neg.length+1]=number;
    else if(number>0)
        pos[pos.length+1]=number;
    else
        zeros[zeros.length+1]=number;
}
int positive=pos.length();
int negative=neg.length();
int zero=zeros.length();
```

Comment: Do you know what a duplicate is?

Comment: I added the duplicates. Is it OK now?

Comment: I assume this question should be solved using only arrays (int[]), maybe you should ask the OP first if other collection types are allowed?

Comment: Where do you actually add values to l1? From what I can see, you are checking against an empty array

Comment: in : else
        l1.add(number);

Comment: ah, i'm blind :p

Comment: This doesn't compile

Comment: actually, I am in outside now